# Error 415 while uploading a file through Postman to ASP.NET Core API

Tags: asp.net-core, postman

I'm trying to upload a file through ASP.NET Core API. My action is:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostImage([FromBody] IFormFile file, [FromRoute] int id)
{
    if(file.Length > 0)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
        var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/images", "Image-" + id + "." + fileExtension);
        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }
        return Ok(fileName + fileExtension);
    }
    return NotFound("File not found!");
}
```

When I use Postman to check its functionality, I encounter Error 415 and Visual Studio does not jump to the breaking point:

> {
> "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13",
> "title": "Unsupported Media Type",
> "status": 415,
> "traceId": "00-d411f8c099a9ca4db6fe04ae25c47411-dadd8cca7cc36e45-00" }

How can I fix this problem in my code?

Comment: If you want to receive `IFormFile` , you need post `content-type=multiple/form-data` which is from form data instead of body. You need change `[FromBody]` to `[FromForm]` and post file from form. If you post file from body, maybe you post a byte array? If though you need change `IFormFile file` to `byte[] file`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to receive `IFormFile`, you need post `content-type=multipart/form-data` which is from **form data** instead of body. Also remember to change `[FromBody]` to `[FromForm]`.

Postman:
[image]

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostImage([FromForm] IFormFile file, [FromRoute] int id)    
{...}
```

If you post file from body, maybe you post a byte array. If though you need change `IFormFile file` to `byte[] file`.